# why do we need private nested interface in java?

Tags: java, inner-classes

What is the use of this private nested interface?

Below code is for reference:

```
class a {
    private static interface Ione {
        void mone();
    }
}
```

Comment: So nested private classes can implement it

Comment: look into So question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71625/why-would-a-static-inner-interface-be-used-in-java

Comment: There's a good answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971554/private-interfaces/17971629#17971629, though the question itself was closed for poor clarity.

Comment: prabhaker my question is about private interface not public interface.

Comment: @andy thomas do you think it is answered? why it is closed without proper explanation.

Comment: @user2489380 The question was not very clear originally (which is why it got closed) - I have reworded it. The answer gives a good example.

Answer (score -1):

You do this when the function of the method only relates to the containing class and even then its not really something you have to do.  This would be one of those coding preference things.  So as an example you would have other classes that want to implement Ione and you would want those other classes to know that Ione is related to class a.

```
public class SomeOtherClass implements a.Ione {
 ...
}
```